# Telnet login in python

Tags: python, telnet, telnetlib, getpass

I have been trying to make a automated python login system, but I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/kali/py.py", line 14, in <module>
    tn.read_until(b"Password: ")   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/telnetlib.py", line 329, in read_until
    return self.read_very_lazy()   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/telnetlib.py", line 405, in read_very_lazy
    raise EOFError('telnet connection closed') EOFError: telnet connection closed
```

The code is:

```
import telnetlib
import getpass


HOST = "127.0.0.1" #not really, I used a real telnet ip
user = input("USERNAME: ")
password = getpass.getpass()

tn = telnetlib.Telnet()
tn.open(HOST)

tn.read_until(b"login: ")
tn.write(user.encode("ascii")+b"\n")
tn.read_until(b"Password: ")
tn.write(password.encode("ascii")+b"\n")
tn.write(b"exit\n")
print(tn.read_all())
tn.close()
```

I REALLY need help with this, but if you don't know how, could someone please tell me how to do it in terminal, like a all in one command? telnet --user admin --password 1234 127.0.0.1 or something like that.

Comment: Does this work if you telnet in from a command line?

Comment: @TimRoberts I can connect via the command "telnet"

Comment: And you see the string "Password: ", spelled exactly like that?

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes, login: admin
Password: 
is displayed (I entered admin).

Comment: I don't really think it will help, but what if you remove the last space in `"Password: "`?